# Dynamically instantiate objects when they're first invoked in autofac c#

Tags: c#, reflection, dependency-injection, autofac

Im trying to figure out how to dynamically instantiate class when it's first used. Something like autofac's Lazy does but without refactoring all my classes.

Is there any possiblity to do something like this:

```
public class MyService : IMyService {
    public MyService() {
        // I want it to be invoked only if SomeMethod was invoked before.
        // 1. Attempt to invoke SomeMethod
        // 2. call MyService.constructor
        // 3. invoke MyService.SomeMethod()
    }
    public void SomeMethod() {
        ///literally any code.
    }

}
```

It has to be done without changing existing codebase (except services registration/ autofac setup or other areas that could be changed without much effort), and all services look's like that:

```
public class Service : IService {
    public Service(AnotherService service){
        ///...
    }

}
```

My initial idea was to create Proxy class and then while registering services wrap it with that proxy.

It could look something like this:

```
    public class Proxy<T>
    {
        private T _target;
        private bool instantiated = false;

        private void Instantiate()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Creating instance");
            _target = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
        }
        public void xxx() - this method should be called every time any wrapped type method get's called.
        {
            if (instantiated == false)
            {
                Instantiate();
                instantiated = true;
            }

            /// proceed with invocation. (im not sure how to do this via reflection).
        }
    }
```

The main issue with this idea is that above proxy class should be created at runtime via reflection and it has to mimic wrapping class behaviour.

I'd appreciate any advice on how to approach this problem.
All i want to lazy create dependencies in autofac container (currently if dependency A is requiring dependency B then B is instantiated, i want change this to instantiate B only if any method from A calls B.method).

Thanks!

Comment: "I want it to be invoked only if SomeMethod was invoked before." I don't understand what that sentence means.  Your question is not clear.

Comment: Can't you register IMyService with autofac as usual and where it is used use `Lazy<IMyService>` ?

Comment: I meant that i want constructor to be invoked only if this class was called before. Lazy instantiating just before method invocation. 

@Fildor i could do that, but it would require to rewrite PLENTY of services and their usages.

Comment: Why do you need your object to be instantiated lazily? Are you [doing too much inside your constructors?](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/03/03/InjectionConstructorsshouldbesimple/).

Comment: I'm sure we're just getting words mixed up but this - "I meant that i want constructor to be invoked only if this class was called before" - is almost exactly, precisely the opposite of how constructors work. The constructor is invoked when the class is instantiated - not before - and never again for the life of that class instance.

Comment: @ScottHannen I know that consturctor has to be instantiated first. But if you wrap this with proxy class then wrapped class can be instantiated AFTER attempting to call it.

Comment: Sorry, it's a job hazard. Sometimes I take things very literally.

Comment: That's cool Scott ;) Actually i need something that will be instantiated INSTEAD of target class and manage it's lifetime and mimic it's all properties/methods. Something like @Steven proposed bellow. But it need to be done for every service in my container.

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is the Proxy pattern. You can create a lazy proxy as follows:

```cs
public class LazyMyServiceProxy : IMyService
{
    private readonly Lazy<MyService> lazy;
    public LazyMyServiceProxy(Lazy<MyService> lazy) => this.lazy = lazy;

    public void SomeMethod() => this.lazy.SomeMethod();
}
```

You can use this proxy using the following Autofac registrations.

```cs
builder.RegisterType<MyService>();
builder.RegisterType<LazyMyServiceProxy>().As<IMyService>();
```

Comment: Exactly. But i need to create that kind of proxy dynamically for EVERY service in my app. Preferably during registration in container.

Comment: EVERY service?? That's raises a big red flag in my head. What do you need this for? Are you violating this rule https://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/03/03/InjectionConstructorsshouldbesimple/ big time?

Comment: Yeah, every service seems like... bad times indeed. I can't think of a way you'd be able to do that out of the box in Autofac and it's not something we'd intentionally put there. You might be able to do some fancy wizardry with Castle.DynamicProxy but it'd be totally custom.

Comment: Autofac.Extras.DynamicProxy uses Castle.DynamicProxy. But I looked at it and didn't see any way that I would want to do this. I have no doubt that it's doable, but the work would be greater than just modifying the services that actually need the change (which it's hard to imagine being all of them.) And then if you did all that work, it would be confusing and difficult to trust. It would require some serious unit testing.

Comment: Im not violating simple constructor rule. Every constructor is simple, but we have dozens of services and it takes some time to load them all. If all of them would be lazy loaded then startup wouldn't require that much time to happen. 

Maybe i should provide more detailed description why i need this. I want to upgrade our integration test environment. Currently we're registering required services in test startup. I've registered all services in test base class, but now it takes 3x longer to run our integration tests (from 1.5 minutes to 5 minutes). This would be done only in test. @Steven

Comment: @TravisIllig do you see any way of speeding up tests in case described aboove ?